# Is "caught you unawares" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

I read a book and came across "caught you unawares". I kept thinking it's supposed to be "caught you unaware".

Is this an acceptable form or was that a typo or something?

Comment: Same here. Heard that on one WW 2 documentary series, "...it [Pearl Harbor bombing] catches the Americas totally unawares." Was used by a BE speaker. Love his accent :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a correct form.  `Unawares` is an adverb meaning "while not aware of something" or "by surprise".  `Caught` needs an adverb complement, so `unawares` fits nicely.  It turns out `unawares` was actually Random House's word of the day several years back, and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20070217123544/http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000619) does a nice job of explaining it.

Comment: I generally agree that quoting is preferable, but given the length of the cited material, in this case I thought that it was reasonable to simply link.  The wayback machine captured it, so it's available now at: https://web.archive.org/web/20070217123544/http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000619   I'll edit the answer to update.

Answer (score 2):

It's the correct form, "unawares"is the adverb form of the adjective  "unaware" and caught calls for an adverb complement rather than an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, couldn't resist:

> Bananas in pyjamas
>     Are coming down the stairs
>     Bananas in pyjamas
>     Are coming down in pairs
>     Bananas in pyjamas
>     Are chasing teddy bears
>     'Cause on Tuesdays
>     They all try to
>     Catch them unawares

Comment: I'm reminded of a song on Cheech and Chong's *Up in Smoke*.